# Pydrake error with PortDataType in MakeFiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulator

Tags: drake

I'm getting the following error and am not sure how to resolve it: `Failure at systems/controllers/finite_horizon_linear_quadratic_regulator.cc:53 in RiccatiSystem(): condition 'input_port_->get_data_type() == PortDataType::kVectorValued' failed.`

After creating my plant from `AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph` and loading in a urdf, I tried passing `plant.DeclareInputPort` a parameter to `plant.DeclareInputPort` but still got the same error. How can I properly change the data type of the input port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulatorOptions](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/structdrake_1_1systems_1_1controllers_1_1_finite_horizon_linear_quadratic_regulator_options.html) takes an optional `input_port_index`, which should probably be set to `plant.get_actuation_input_port()` if you are using it with `MultiBodyPlant`.

Comment: Yes, it worked once I added `options.input_port_index = plant.get_actuation_input_port().get_index()`. Thanks!